# Best approach for passing database record to new activity

Tags: android, sqlite, optimization

I'm writing an Android app that relies heavily on the sqlite database. I'm not clear on what's the best (most efficient in terms of memory and resources) way to pass the record data from one activity to the next. For instance, there's an activity in which you view a customer record, and then can click an action menu item to edit the record. At the moment, I pass the table name and record ID to the new activity via the `Intent` that opens it, and in the new activity I re-extract all the data from the database. It just occurred to me, however, that perhaps it would be better (i.e. more efficient) to pass an object containing all the record's data, which has methods to update or delete the record.  Each table has only up to a dozen or so columns, so the object would be quite small, although in some cases in order to accomodate one-to-one or one-to-many relationships between tables, the data object passed by the `Intent` would contain one or more data objects as fields.  I'm looking for pros and cons, and if possible a definitive ruling on the best solution.

**THIS**

(view record activity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditRecordActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(TABLE_NAME, tableName);
intent.putExtra(RECORD_ID, recordId);
startActivity(intent);
```

(edit record activity)

```
String tableName = getIntent().getStringExtra(ViewRecordActivity.TABLE_NAME);
String recordId = getIntent().getStringExtra(ViewRecordActivity.RECORD_ID);
Cursor c = db.query(tableName, DB_COLUMNS, "_ID = ?",new String[]{ recordId }, null,null, null);
// populate EditText fields with data from Cursor
```

**OR THIS**

(customer class)

```
public class Customer extends Record{
  String id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String phone;

  public Customer(int recordId, String table){
    Cursor c = db.query(table, DB_COLUMNS, "_ID = ?",new String[]{ recordId }, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    id = c.getString[0];
    firstName = c.getString[1];
    lasstName = c.getString[2];
    phone = c.getString[3];
    c.close();
  }
}
```

(view record activity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditRecordActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(RECORD, customer);
startActivity(intent);
```

(edit record activity)

```
Record r = getIntent().getExtras().getExtra(ViewRecordActivity.RECORD);
// populate fields directly from data object, no call to database until changes are saved
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General Concept:

When you are facing with this issue you just need to think:

1.In case you have a lot of data the only solution is lazy loading, That means load data only when you need it.. It will cause hitting the DB few times and your software will be slower because I/O actions are "Expensive"

2.In case you have small data, You can consider this both options:
- Does your small data can grow sometimes? If yes so you have to help you app be scalable.. So lazy loading is the right option.

3.In case the data is small and constant you can load it once and the start of the application and pass it on between activties.. You don't need more than 1 query and your app will be faster

This is basically all the options :)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

> At the moment, I pass the table name and record ID to the new activity
>   via the Intent that opens it, and in the new activity I re-extract all
>   the data from the database.

I would suggest that you add a custom unique `id` identifier to the `Object` data model
along with a variable that defines which database the `Object` belongs to. By doing this, you avoid a query.

> It just occurred to me, however, that perhaps it would be better
>   (i.e. more efficient) to pass an object containing all the record's
>   data, which has methods to update or delete the record.

One of the problems that you will face when trying to pass a custom `Object` across `Activities` is that you will need to make the `Object` implement the `Parcelable` interface. This is required so Android knows how to marshall/unmarshall your `Object`.

One thing I can suggest you do is look into DAO (i.e. [GreenDAO](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO) or [ORMLite](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android) libraries. They simplify interacting with databases quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the first one and query the values in the `onCreate` of the 2nd activity.  The reason for this is that the record will be re-queried every time the activity is created, and then can pick up the latest information in case anything has changed the record in the background.  So if a user launches an activity from recents, it could bypass the activity before it and have stale data.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: While at this point the app is entirely native, I do plan to introduce cloud-synching across multiple devices, in which case your point becomes relevant. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Your welcome.  If you do do it at the activity level, you should perform the queries off the main thread as @Aviad hinted towards.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that. My code examples were simplified for obvious reasons...